# How to initialize objects with different object_id in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, initialization

If I initialize objects with assignment like `a = b = c = []`

then this variables have the same object_ids: `a.object_id == b.object_id == c.object_id`

Also I tried:

```
[a, b, c].map {|e| e = [] }

a, b, c = Array.new(3, [])

a, b, c = Array.new(3, Array.new)
```

but it doensn't initialize a, b, c variables with *different* object_ids

Is there a way to initialize variables a, b, c with different object ids but with the same value == []?

Answer (score 8):

How about these possible solutions:

```
a,b,c=[],[],[]
a,b,c=(0..2).map{[]}
a,b,c=Array.new(3){[]}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
```

Comment: I want to remove many lines with assignment with [] in my code, that's  why I posted this question.

Comment: @sharipov_ru: see another answer then.

Comment: How many such lines you have? More than three suggest code smell.

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović, you right. I found 5 lines in one method and want to replace its with a,b,c=Array.new(3){[]} Howard's solution.

Comment: @sharipov_ru: I'd say that `a,b,c = Array.new(3){[]}` smells much stronger. I'd never allow this kind of [refuctoring](http://www.waterfall2006.com/gorman.html) in my team.